# "not like" operator

Tags: r, dplyr, operators

Is there a possibility to use filtering in dplyr and use negative of like operator? Something like (which does not work):

```
my_df %>% 
  filter(text !%like% "dirty talk")
```

Comment: `filter(!text %like% "dirty talk")` here you go dirty boy

Comment: Place the `!` operator at the beginning of the condition, like so: `! text %like% ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like this:

```
my_df %>% 
    filter(!text %like% "dirty talk")
```

Since placing the exclamation like so makes the statement `not`

Answer (score 3):

Adding the ! at the start of the condition is a great option. If you want a different direction, you can create your own function, which I did as an analog to %in%:

```
`%notin%` <- Negate('%in%')
```

So in your case, create a function like this:

```
`%notlike%` <- Negate('%like%')
```

Answer (score 0):

tidyverse style:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df %>% filter(!str_detect(text,'dirty talk')
```